# Spritekit app will not run on iOS7.1.2 device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am new to iSO development so I maybe missing the obvious here.

I attemoted to run a sprite kit game developed in Xcode 5, on a iPhone device with iOS6.
I soon learned that sprite kit will not run on iOS 6, so I update iPhone software
to iOS 7.1.2.

However Xcode will not display the iPhone as a device that the app can be tested on, in the Oragniser I get this message:

> The version of iOS on “iPhone” is not supported by this installation
>   of the iOS SDK. Please restore the device to a version of the OS
>   listed below, or update to the latest version of the iOS SDK; which is
>   available here.

There is no version

> listed below

, I am assuming it is Xcode 6.

So I am somewhat confused, I don't want to update to Xcode 6 just yet, so what version of Xcode is iOS 7.1.2 actually compatible with? i.e. what iOS do i need on my phone for a sprite kit app developed in Xcode 5 to run on??

I would of thought a sprite kit should run on all iOS7 and greater?

Thanks
Ciaran

Comment: Xcode 5.1 should work with iOS 7.1.

Comment: That would make sense but can't understand the error I get in Xcode when connecting the device

Comment: Is it possible to download SDK 7.1 for Xcode 5?

Comment: Just update to Xcode 5.1.

Comment: where do i find 5.1? can only see ver 6 on app store...

Comment: Go to https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action and click the link for downloading earlier versions of Xcode.